# readlines() error with for-loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, readlines

This error is hard to describe because I can't figure out how the loop is even affecting the `readline()` and `readlines()` Methods. When I try using the former, I get these unexpected Traceback errors. When I try the latter, my code runs and nothing happens. I have determined that the bug is located in the first eight lines. The first few lines of the `Topics.txt` file is posted.

**`Code`**

```
import requests
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Url = "https://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/"
Topicfilename = "Topics.txt"
Topicfile = open(Topicfilename, 'r')
Line = Topicfile.readlines()
Linenumber = 0
for Line in Topicfile:
    Linenumber += 1
    print("Reading line", Linenumber)

    Topic = Line
    Newtopic = Topic.strip("\n").replace(' ', '').replace(',', '')
    print(Newtopic)
    Link = Url.join(Newtopic)
    print(Link)
    Sourcecode = requests.get(Link)
```

When I run this bit here, it prints the the URL preceded by the first character of the line.For example, it prints as 2https://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/4https://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/Hhttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/ etc. for 24 Hour Fitness.

**`Topics.txt`**

- 21st Century Fox
- 24 Hour Fitness
- 2K Games
- 3M

**`Full Error`**

> Reading line 1 24HourFitness
>   2https://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/4https://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/Hhttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/ohttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/uhttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/rhttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/Fhttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/ihttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/thttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/nhttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/ehttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/shttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/s
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Caden\Desktop\Programs\LususStudios\AutoDealBot\HashtagScanner.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       Sourcecode = requests.get(Link)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.10.0-py3.4.egg\requests\api.py",
>   line 71, in get
>       return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.10.0-py3.4.egg\requests\api.py",
>   line 57, in request
>       return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.10.0-py3.4.egg\requests\sessions.py",
>   line 475, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.10.0-py3.4.egg\requests\sessions.py",
>   line 579, in send
>       adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.10.0-py3.4.egg\requests\sessions.py",
>   line 653, in get_adapter
>       raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url) requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were
>   found for
>   '2https://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/4https://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/Hhttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/ohttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/uhttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/rhttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/Fhttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/ihttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/thttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/nhttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/ehttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/shttps://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/s'

Comment: The file is read in one gulp with `Line = Topicfile.readlines()`. Just eliminate that line.

Comment: Under the hood, the *readlines* method "consumes" the file, so when it returns the underlying file position pointer is at the end of the file. Then you try to read the file some more in the for loop, but since it's already at the end it does nothing. Use only one of the two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues:

1. You seem to be iterating over `Topicfile` instead of `Topicfile.readLines()`.
2. `Url.join(Newtopic)` isn't returning what you think it is. `.join` takes a list (in this case, a string is a list of characters) and will insert `Url` in between each one.

Here is code with these problems addressed:

```
import requests

Url = "https://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/"
Topicfilename = "topics.txt"
Topicfile = open(Topicfilename, 'r')
Lines = Topicfile.readlines()
Linenumber = 0
for Line in Lines:
    Linenumber += 1
    print("Reading line", Linenumber)

    Topic = Line
    Newtopic = Topic.strip("\n").replace(' ', '').replace(',', '')
    print(Newtopic)
    Link = '{}{}'.format(Url, Newtopic)
    print(Link)
    Sourcecode = requests.get(Link)
```

As an aside, I also recommend using lowercased variable names since camel case is generally reserved for class names in Python :)

Comment: Yes, thank you! I didn't even think about the adjoining of the two variables affecting the for-loop. I have revised my code to `Link = Url + Newtopic`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, python conventions are to lowercase all variable names.

Secondly, you are exhausting the file pointer when you read all the lines at first, then continue to loop over the file.

Try to simply open the file, then loop over it

```
linenumber = 0
with open("Topics.txt") as topicfile:
    for line in topicfile:
        # do work 
        linenumber += 1
```

Then, the issue in the traceback, if you look closely, you are building up this really long url string and that's definitely not a url, so requests throws an error

`InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '2https://ritetag.com/best-hashtags-for/4https://ritetag.com/...`

And you can debug to see that `Url.join(Newtopic)` is "interleaving" the `Url` String between each character of the `Newtopic` list, which is what `str.join` will do